# should wsdl+xsd be designed in a way that it can be seen directly what is the content of the messages?

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, xsd

I'm implementing a CRUD web service for object with multiple attributes. Should I define a single type like

```
<xs:complexType name="tProject">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
  <xs:element name="projectname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  <xs:element name="projectnum" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

  <!-- here another 30-some attributes -->
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and use it for all operations:

1. GetProject both request and response contain tProject. In response all fields would be there but request should contain key columns (id and/or projectname) to identify the project. This is something that the consumer just have to know and it's not clearly stated in interface description.
2. UpdateProject request should contain key columns (id and/or projectname) and the columns that are updated. Once again it can't be known by just checking the interface cause all are minOccurs="0".
3. CreateProject request should contain some fields that are wanted to have initially for the project. The id is created by WS and it must be sent back to consumer. Response would be again tProject but only having id in it.

Already when I wrote it here it feels that it violates everything about wsdl design.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my own question. I hope I'll get much better answers but it would be nice to here what's wrong with my next approach:

```
<!-- only updatable fielsds here -->
<xs:complexType name="tProjectBase">
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="projectnum" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="accepteddate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="activeyears" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- extending updateble with keys and not updateble -->
<xs:complexType name="tProject">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="tProjectBase">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="projectname" type="member"/>
      <xs:element name="projectcreator" type="xs:string" /> <!--not updatable-->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- only keys here -->
<xs:complexType name="tProjectKeys">
  <xs:choice>
   <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
   <xs:element name="projectname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="tUpdateProject">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="keys" type="tProjectKeys" />
    <xs:element name="project" type="tProjectBase" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="tCreateProject">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="projectcreator" type="xs:string />
    <xs:element name="project" type="tProjectBase" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

- GetProject

  - request = tProjectKeys
  - reponse = tProject
- UpdateProject

  - request  = tUpdateProject
  - response = nothing (all messages are supposed to have header which have status)
- CreateProject

  - request = tCreateProject
  - response = id of the created project

There's problems with this approach also. For example now the keys are "hard-coded". What if some customers would have projectnum as unique and would like to use that as key to update project from external system. Maybe that is the information that their external system uses. So the original question's scheme is more flexible. But which way to go?